# Stuck on CNF conversion?

Tags: logic

I am trying to convert the following to CNF:

$$(P → (Q → R)) → (P → (R → Q))$$

I've done some of it but I'm unsure of what I am supposed to do after this. Here is what I have gotten so far.

$$¬(P \to (Q \to R)) ∨ ( P \to (R \to Q)$$

$$¬(P \to (¬Q ∨ R)) ∨ ( P \to (¬R ∨ Q) $$

$$¬(¬P ∨ (¬Q ∨ R)) ∨ ( ¬P ∨ (¬R ∨ Q) $$

$$(P ∧ ¬(¬Q ∨ R)) ∨ ( ¬P ∨ (¬R ∨ Q) $$

$$(P ∧ (Q ∧ ¬R)) ∨ ( ¬P ∨ (¬R ∨ Q) $$

$$(P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ ( ¬P ∨ ¬R ∨ Q) $$

$$(P ∧ Q ∧ ¬R) ∨  ¬P ∨ ¬R ∨ Q $$

$$\neg P \lor \neg R \lor Q$$

I just don't know what to do when I get here. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $\neg P\vee\neg R\vee Q$ *is* conjunctive normal: it is a conjunctive sequence of terms that are purely disjunctions of literals (or negations of such).  There is just one such term in the sequence, is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the second set of parentheses, and the $P \land Q \land \neg R$ term gets absorbed by $\neg R$, which leaves you with:

$\neg P \lor \neg R \lor Q$

which is in CNF!

So use the following general equivalence principle:

**Absorption**

$P \lor (P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow P$

Comment: So, ¬R is logically equivalent to  P∧Q∧¬R, meaning we can drop that and be left with ¬P∨¬R∨Q? How do we know that the ¬R is the one that is logically equivalent and not ¬P or Q?

Comment: @name. not quite: $\neg R$ is equivalent to $(P \land Q \land \neg R) \lor \neg R$. And yes, we could also have absorbed that term using $Q$ ... But not with the $\neg P$

Comment: I think I understand it but I am not sure where the ¬P came from. NVM, just saw your edit.

Comment: @name. That one was the one you got from converting the $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$ ... Which you all did correctly by the way!

Comment: Thank your for all your help. I believe I understand it now, but I am not sure how exactly to write that in my solution. May you check my edited post and give me feedback on how I wrote the solution? Thanks :)

Comment: Not quite right ... I'll edit it!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!!!

Comment: @name no problem ... Do you see what happens at the end and how that is an example of Absorption?